# Are there any probabilistic models of computation that can strongly simulate themselves?

Tags: turing-machines, quantum-computing, simulation, probabilistic-turing-machines

I was reading this question over on the [quantum computation stackexchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/why-cant-a-quantum-computer-strongly-simulate-itself), and the top answer stated that you can't (strongly) simulate even a probabilistic turing machine, on itself. I was just curious if there are any computational models (that are probabilistic) that can be strongly simulated by themselves. If there is, what would it look like?

Strong simulation based on the link I provided is explained here:

> We can strongly simulate a machine if we can estimate the probability of measuring some fixed output - all zeroes, say - at the end to within some fixed relative error.